# Jaspersoft 5.6.1 server Image - Lock position in Excel export

Tags: jasper-reports, export-to-excel, jasperserver

I've designed a Jasperreport using studio 5.6.1 which has got images. When I export to excel from Studio, it works fine. When I upload to the server and then export to excel (xls or xlsx) the Image postion moves down or up.This creates a extra row in excel and causing a alignment issue.

Is there a way to lock the Image postion or is there any property to set at element level? Please advise

Thanks

Sreeram
P.S I couldn't share this jrxml, as this is strict policy posting code on forums. Sorry!!!! :(

Comment: `I couldn't share this jrxml, as this is strict policy posting code on forums` - How we can help you? What if to make the simple jrxml file to reproduce the problem and post it...

Comment: Hi 

Thanks Alex for the reply. 

I managed to solve the issue by placing the static text above and below the image, so the image wouldn't move. Also I removed Frame which was surrounding the image.

Thanks

Sreeram